# Install Plotly Dash in Databricks

Tags: plotly, databricks, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am trying to use Plotly Dash in Databricks, but I get the following error:

`'DummyMod' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

First, I install Dash library in Databricks and its requirements.

Then, I use the following piece of code to initialize Dash.

```
from dash import Dash, dash_table, dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = Dash(__name__)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: how do you install library on Databricks cluster?

Comment: @AlexOtt `%pip install dash` I installed the other dash libraries and its dependencies in the same way. It does not give me an error, so I assume it has been installed correctly.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. If there is a workaround that would be nice to hear